# eloquent query on 2 conditions from the same field

Tags: laravel

In Laravel how do you query a item to be either FALSE or NULL.

`return $this->model->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhere('invisible', '=', null)...`

Because this that I wrote above, does not seem to do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$this->model->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
        ->orWhere('invisible', '=', null);
})...
```

[Parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping)